# UIImagePickerController Overlay takePicture method

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am calling an camera overlay using a xib file by doing the following:

Camera.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ControlsViewController.h"

@interface CameraViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,ProcessDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

@end
```

Camera.m

```
#import "CameraViewController.h"
#import "ControlsViewController.h"

@interface CameraViewController ()

@end

@implementation CameraViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    //Get the camera
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];
    self.imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;



    //set our custom overlay view
    ControlsViewController *overlayViewController = [[ControlsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ControlsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:overlayViewController];
    self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayViewController.view;

    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:NULL];

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)didClickCameraButton {
    [self.imagePicker takePicture];
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

This calls the xib and .m .h files for `ControlsViewController` Within those file I have a button for taking the picture but not sure how to call that method in the overlay. I was thinking of something like:

Overlay.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ProcessDataDelegate <NSObject>


@end

@interface ControlsViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

{
    id <ProcessDataDelegate> delegate;
}


- (IBAction)cameraButton:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)kennedyButton:(id)sender;


@property (retain) id delegate;
-(void)didClickCameraButton;


@end
```

Overlay.M

```
#import "ControlsViewController.h"
#import "CameraViewController.h"

@interface ControlsViewController ()

@end

@implementation ControlsViewController

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

     [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/



- (IBAction)cameraButton:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"this button works");
    [self.delegate didClickCameraButton];


}

- (IBAction)kennedyButton:(id)sender {

     NSLog(@"this button works");
}
@end
```

but obviously the imagePicker property is not being carried over the the overlays .m file. Anyone know how to go about this? I imported the cameras .H file on the overlays .m file as well but no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your overlayViewController, is the button linked to cameraButton:? You have several layers of controls, and ultimately you want the main controller (the one you're showing viewDidLoad for) to call [self.imagePicker takePicture]. You can add a delegate to overlayViewController, so that when cameraButton: is called, it just tells the delegate.

Obviously you'll have to create a protocol, set a delegate, etc.

Edit: usual patterns for delegates are that the delegate is weak. You may have to have the overlayController not be transient if you're using arc.

ControlsViewController.h

```
@interface ControlsViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    // don't need the delegate declared in here
}
@property (weak) id delegate;
```

ControlsViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)cameraButton:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"this button works");

    [self.delegate didClickCameraButton];
}
```

YourMainViewController.h

```
@interface YourMainViewController : UIViewController <ControlsViewDelegate>
{
    ControlsViewController *overlayController;
}
```

YourMainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...

    overlayViewController = [[ControlsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ControlsViewController" bundle:nil];
    overlayViewController.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayViewController.view;

    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:NULL];
}

-(void)didClickCameraButton {
    [self.picker takePicture];
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me I just have never made my own delegate. I got the camera.h to recognize the delegate but the overlay.m file I dont think is telling the delegate the button was pushed. Does the edits above look right?

Comment: yes, it's getting there. One thing I didn't mention is that if you're using ARC you may have to retain the overlay controller inside your main controller, otherwise it gets deallocated, and there's no delegate callback. So make the overlay controller a property.

Comment: Also, typical delegate patterns are weak. I'll edit the answer to show a bit of what I mean.

Comment: Doing this was working but somehow, the overlay view wouldn't rotate with the device. Any ideas?